# Update values in multiple rows in mysql when checkbox is checked

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a checkbox and an input box where I want to insert the value in the text box when the checkbox next to is clicked.

**DB**

| column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | AAA |
| 2 | BBB |
| 3 | CCC |
| 4 | DDD |

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="nid[]" value=1>
<input type="text" name="nname[]" /><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="nid[]" value=2>
<input type="text" name="nname[]" /><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="nid[]" value=3>
<input type="text" name="nname[]" /><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="nid[]" value=4>
<input type="text" name="nname[]" /><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $nid = $_POST['nid'];
    $nname = $_POST['nname'];
    $count = count($_POST['nid']);
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) {
        $sql = "UPDATE table_name SET column2 = $nname[$i] WHERE column1 = $nid[$i]";
        $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    }
?>
```

When I process the above code, mysqli_result finds the value of the check box but always pulls the first value of the input box even though the checkbox next to it is not checked.

Comment: @brombeer Corrected in edit, but still it does not work

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Comment: ...good to know is that the above comment isn't only about security. If your data contains some specific unescaped characters, for example a single quote `'`, your query will break.

Comment: Unchecked checkboxes do not cause an entry in the form submission data set, whereas text fields that are simply left empty, do. So you can not just use `name="foo[]"` in a situation like this - the indexes of your two arrays in $_POST will diverge, if not _all_ checkboxes where checked. You need to specify the index upfront in your field names - `name="foo[0]"`, `name="foo[1]"`, etc. - so that you can properly correlate the checked checkboxes with the text field values.

Comment: @CBroe The HTML in itself is dynamically generated from a previous form and not restricted to only 4 values. If there are 'n' number of values, how do I correlate the checkboxes with the text fields.

Comment: This has nothing to do with what the number actually is. You need to name the fields as I said, and then you loop over `$_POST['nid']` with a foreach loop. Use the key value to access the corresponding element in `$_POST['nname']`.

Comment: If this html is generated from data passed from another page, then I have to assume it is being created IN A LOOP so you have all you need, "a numeric" to use when creating each occurance of these 2 fields